# iOS set default date to date picker?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uidatepicker

I've a date picker associated with a text field.Text field has value like this **Thursday, November 22nd**(string recieved from server call).
Now i want that when i click on text field date picker should sow default date that is displayed in text field.
I guess i've to call `[datePicker setDate:date animated:YES];` but problem is that how to convert  string **Thursday, November 22nd** into `NSDate`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume u would like current year in your date:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSString *yeardate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *string = @"Thursday, November 22nd";
if ( [string length] > 0)
  string = [string substringToIndex:[string length] - 2];

NSString *finalstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",string,yeardate];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE,MMMM dd yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:finalstr];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: And what about "1st, 3rd, 4th"?

Comment: And for "Thursday, November 22nd" the resulting date is 1970-11-22.

Comment: @Prince Is there any way to add current year in date as i'm getting  2000-11-21 18:30:00 +0000, other wise you answer is acceptable...Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the code snippet below

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy"];
NSString *dateStr;
NSDate *date;

date  = [NSDate date];
dateStr= [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateStr); // -> Tuesday November 6, 2012




dateStr= @"Tuesday November 6, 2012";
date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
 NSLog(@"%@",date); // -> 2012-11-05 18:15:00 +0000
```

Comment: Thanks, but my string is like Sunday, October 7th and it will vary

Comment: In that case you can take reference from ICU Date and time formatting to get all posible date formatting options.